# How to Resize button animations programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, translate-animation

I am new to Objective-C. I created an animation that move 3 buttons upwards. These buttons contain images. However, when this button animation occurs it resizes the button images and makes them HUGE. I tried to correct the code below to resize the button images, but I still get HUGE buttons. Can someone please help me? It should be Width:78  Height:76. I tried replacing width and height but it still doesn't work. Note: Just correct the code, I don't need a completely different answer.

```
-(IBAction)Search:(id)sender {

CGFloat screenWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = self.view.bounds.size.height;

CGFloat normalizedX = (124 / 320); // You calculate these 'normalized' numbers, possibly from a designer's spec.
// it's the percent the amount should be over, as number from 0-1.
// This number is based on screen width of 320 having x 124 pt.

CGFloat startingX = normalizedX * screenWidth;
CGFloat startingY = (475 / 200) * screenHeight;
CGFloat width = (42 / 40) * screenWidth;
CGFloat height = (30 / 30) * screenHeight;

CGRect startingRect = CGRectMake(startingX, startingY, width, height);

self.button.frame = startingRect;
self.buttonTwo.frame = startingRect;
self.buttonThree.frame = startingRect;

// animate
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 animations:^{
    CGFloat firstX = (13 / 770) * screenWidth;
    CGFloat lowerY = (403 / 370) * screenHeight;
    self.button.frame = CGRectMake(firstX, lowerY, width, height);

    CGFloat secondX = (124 / 424) * screenWidth;
    CGFloat upperY = (347 / 447) * screenHeight;
    self.buttonTwo.frame = CGRectMake(secondX, upperY, width, height);

    CGFloat thirdX = (232 / 680) * screenWidth;
    self.buttonThree.frame = CGRectMake(thirdX, lowerY, width, height);
}];
 }
```

Comment: Do you want the buttons to jump instantly to the same startingRect, then animate to different destinations?   Do you want their sizes to change at all?  The code posted clearly resizes the buttons, and @DuncanC's observation is spot on about the floating point math.  If you want the buttons to remain a fixed size, then use CGRectOffset on their frames, which only manipulates the origins.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like your height and width math is wrong.

(42/40) * screenWidth will simplify to (1) * screenWidth, or the full width of the screen (The expression `42/40` will be done using integer math, resulting in 1.0. If it used floating point, you'd get 1.05 * screenWidth, which would make the images even bigger.)

You have a similar problem with your height calculation. You are setting the button to be the full height of the screen, and slightly wider.

Comment: Yes, that's the code I am having trouble with. I changed it SO many times yet it doesn't change the size of the buttons. It should be Width: 78 Height: 76. What would you change it to? Thanks for the help!